# How to align test in CSS

Tags: css, text, alignment, block

I am working on a chat and I have a problem with CSS.

This is how it looks like: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v7vV.png]

This is how I wish it to look like: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v7vV.png]

How do I do it?

Comment: We are going to have to see some code here... preferably a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I don't have an exact code. The testing code is there: http://jsfiddle.net/zVnND/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guessed at the markup but what about something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/YnPU2/?

html:

```
<p>
    <span class="time">20:20:20</span>
    <span class="author">quwquu</span>
    <span class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
</p>
<p>
    <span class="time">20:20:22</span>
    <span class="author">dfghdg</span>
    <span class="text">when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
</p>​
```

css:

```
p { overflow: hidden; vertical-align: top; }
p span { display: table-cell; }
p .time { width: 62px; }
p .author { width: auto; padding-right: 9px; }
p .text { width: auto; }​
```

Answer (score 0):

use for example this css:

```
p {
    text-indent: -50px; //put your first line 50px to the left
    margin-left: 50px; //put the rest 50px to the right
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I guess setting an exact size is not the solution because the next line of text should start there where nickname ends.
Also text is in one <p>text sdfsdf sdff</p> sorry that I didn't explain it better.